# Is there assertCountEqual equivalent in javascript unittests jest library?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have jest unittests with assertion on list of objects which passes on one environment and fails on other, when order of result list changes. I'm looking for some `assertCountEqual`(python) equivalent for `jest` library. I'd appricieate any help. 
I tried adding `sort()` to my assertion but there are custom objects in the list and it isn't as simple as: `expect(list1.sort()).toEqual(list2.sort());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jest` does not support such assertions but you could write your own functions:

1. Custom comparator like described in many articles:

   ```js
   function customFieldCompare(a, b){
       const customField1= a.customField;
       const customField2= b.customField;
       if (customField1 > customField2) {
           return -1;
       }
       if (customField2 > customField1) {
           return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   which can be used together with simple `expect toEqual`

   ```js
   expect(list1.sort(customFieldCompare)).toEqual(list2.sort(customFieldCompare));
   ```
2. Custom `assertCountEqual`

   ```js
   function customAssertCountEqual(array1, array2){
       expect(array1.length).toEqual(array2.length);
       array1.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
         expect(array2).toContainEqual(arrayItem)
       });
   }
   ```